# Worker thread in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to make a simple worker thread inside a same class. However, there are 3 major problems that I am facing, which are:

1. **Definition** of a thread function in class header.
2. Thread function **call**.
3. Called thread function **format**.

I am also confused to use either AfxBeginThread or CreateThread function call to pass multiple thread parameters. Can anyone please provide me a simple worker thread to run in MFC based on the 3 things that I have provided above?

Comment: Just read the documentation. Training on finding things in documentation will save you a lot of time later. It also saves the time of the unfortunate people who might think they should do it for you.

Comment: As this appears to be a homework type question, perhaps it would be better to start by showing us what you have done so far, and then get advise from there.

Answer (score 1):

Definition of a thread function in class header:  It has to be a static member because the usual way of putting "this" in a hidden parameter doesn't work.  Since you only get one parameter, you want the parameter to be a pointer to a struct, and one member of the struct can be "this" of the class instance that your static member can call.

Thread function call: Since the function that gets called is going to use MFC, it is easiest to have the caller call AfxBeginThread.  Since you say the thread will be a worker thread, call the version of AfxBeginThread that is designed for worker threads (even if it doesn't matter much).

Called thread function format.  MSDN describes AfxBeginThread and says what prototype must be used for the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should never be using CreateThred. And if you're using MFC, you MUST use AfxBeginThread to for creating threads.

I've given some explanation here in this discussion: http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread249210.html

Comment: This is outdated myths on the internet for years. It doesn't make any difference anymore (since VS2005) if you use CreateThread API, the begin_thread CRT or the AfxBeginThread API. I did invest a some time to check this and rumors about memory leaks (cause by thread locals etc.). My advise is to always use CreateThread and never begin_thread.

Comment: There's no such thing as begin_thread; perhaps you missed that crucial information in your research. Also, why does it not make any difference since VS 2005? If you link to the single threaded version of CRT and call CreateThread (without any regards to what version of visual studio is being used), the API will still create threads, which will be disastrous as I explained in the other link.

Answer (score 0):

CreateThread is mainly for UI Threads but is still preferred to use the second method for AfxBeginThread. Store a reference to the threads handle in the header not the thread.

```
HANDLE hThread;
```

then in source start your thread pointing to your proc:

```
CWinThread *pThread;
if(!(pThread = AfxBeginThread(ThreadProc, NULL, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0,     CREATE_SUSPENDED))) {
delete arr;
} 
::DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), pThread->m_hThread, GetCurrentProcess(), &hThread, 0, FALSE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);

pThread->ResumeThread();
```

You start it suspended so you can copy the handle to the one you have stored in header. this way you can use the stored handle to check on exitcode.